# Why does enumerating DirectoryEntry children only return 20 results on a WinNT domain? C#

Tags: c#, enumeration, directoryentry

I'm currently using the following code to find computers in a given WinNT domain, since DirectorySearcher is not supported on WinNT domains;

```
protected void ScanDomain(string domainName, bool isLocalDomain)
{
    DirectoryEntry parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry();

    if(isLocalDomain)
    {
        try
        {
            parentEntry.Path = "WinNT://" + domainName;

            int numResults = 0;
            foreach (DirectoryEntry childEntry in parentEntry.Children)
            {
                switch (childEntry.SchemaClassName)
                {
                    case "Computer":
                        Debug.WriteLine(childEntry.Name);

                        numResults++;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (numResults == 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("No results.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But when using this method, I only receive 20 computer results even though I know there's more computers than that in the domain.

So I was just wondering if anyone had any idea why this is?

Comment: I ran your code here and it returned well over 20 computer results. Perhaps there's some restrictions somewhere. Our domain is at Windows Server 2000 (or maybe 2003?) functional level.

Comment: Interesting. There may very well be some restrictions on my network then.

Comment: I think you need to search all the child objects that are containers. If I recall correctly, if computer accounts are within those child objects, they won't show up at the root, and I believe this applies whether it's a WinNT or LDAP domain.  (Sorry this is a bit vague - long time since I've done this...)

Comment: `DirectoryEntry` implements `IDisposable`. Just wanted to point out that best practice is generally to place the parentEntry reference in a using block such that its Dispose method will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Directory Entry returns the children of Specific Node. This will not contain node under nodes, means grand children of that. Try to check for grand children also, and get every node under WIN NT this will work.

Please let me know if you want a code snippet. Or I am missing any thing from my side.